# replace a substring in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string in java script

```
<select name="random[]" class="myclass" id="x"> 
     <option>hello</option>
</select>
```

How can I replace value of id with some other value in javascript?

Comment: `document.getElementById('x').id = 'y'`

Comment: what do you mean by substring? you appear to be replacing the id of an element

Comment: @juhana This is going to replace the id of actual element in HTML, but i have this select element which i am getting into JS as string, I want to change id value and then append this element back into HTML.

Comment: Why can't you first append and then change the id?

Comment: if I am going to append same element back I will have 2 element with same ID and i wont be able to differentiate.

Answer (score 2):

```
 var str = '<select name="random[]" class="myclass" id="x"> <option>hello</option></select><select name="random[]" class="myclass" id="xzzz"> <option>hello</option></select>'; 


rep='id="new value"';

new_str=str.replace(/id="[a-zA-Z0-9]+"/g, rep);

alert(new_str);
```

If there are more occurences of id=...

Comment: If it worked, perhaps you would want to select it as the answer?

Answer (score 1):

i think this will work.

```
var e = document.getElementById("x");
e.id = "y";
```